# Django: Integrity error UNIQUE constraint failed: user_profile.user_id

Tags: django

When I am trying to edit a profile to add info to a UserProfile model, I am getting this strange error:

```
IntegrityError at /profiles/edit/
UNIQUE constraint failed: user_profile.user_id
```

What is wrong here,

model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    phone= models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=1)
```

form:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('phone','age','gender','address','bio')
```

view:

```
def edit_profile(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        print request.POST
        if form.is_valid():

            new_profile = UserProfile(
                            user = request.user,
                            bio = request.POST['bio'],
                            address = request.POST['address'],
                            age = request.POST['age']
                            )

            new_profile.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user_public_profile', args=(request.user.username,)))
        return render(request,'users/edit_profile.html', {'form': form})

    else:
        form = UserProfileForm()
        return render(request,'users/edit_profile.html',
                          {'form': form})
```

Comment: Not specific to your problem but I ran across the same error when I was accidentally altering object fields on a `ModelForm.save(commit=False)`, or at least it was related to how I was handling `commit`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's not strange. You already have a profile for that user, so adding another one breaks the unique constraint. You need to edit the existing one, not add a new one.

Also note that you're not using the cleaned form data when you save, which you should be. Either use `form.cleaned_data['bio']` etc, or even better just do `form.save()` which is the whole point of using a model form.

Putting that together:

```
try:
    profile = request.user.userprofile
except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
    profile = UserProfile(user=request.user)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect...
else:
    form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)
return render...
```

Answer (score 9):

I was getting the same error multiple times and I was really disheartened but finally came over the solution.

Convert:

```py
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

to

```py
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

This should solve the issue.

Comment: but someone needs OneToOneFields then it will be wrong idea

Comment: this worked for me but trying to register a user, i get 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'. How do i solve this?

Comment: @elderlee You can set related_name="user" to use profile.user

Comment: Saved my day buddy <3

Comment: adding related_name = "user" is actually no ideal because it brings more errors while trying to filter for me. all i did was delete the migrations, did user = models.Foreignkey(User)  made migrations  and migrate then changed it back to user = models.OneToOneField(User) and made migrations and migrate and everything worked fine.

Comment: I think you should edit `ForiegnKey` to  `ForeignKey`. It might trip up beginners.

Comment: But you don't want a ForeignKey relationship between user and profile. It must be a One to One, otherwise you can have users with many profiles.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case: If the same user makes the post request again on URL 'profile/edit' then your code will try to create the new UserProfile using the same user instance, but since this is a one to one field and you have already created one profile using that user hence it will throw integrity error.

So you should check first if the profile associated with that user already exists or not, then if it didn't exist then create it.

Comment: This is the proper solution to the problem, not converting `OneToOne` to `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 0):

add (instance = request.user) in  UserProfileForm(request.POST)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It is not really clear from your posting what code should be added to where. Some additionally words of reasoning would also help.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally got this error because I forgot to specify `update_fields` in my call to `save`. I had:

```
modified_instance.save(video_attr)
```

When I should have had:

```
modified_instance.save(update_fields=[video_attr])
```

The truthy string was being interpreted as the positional `force_update` parameter, which obviously causes problems if the record already exists.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you are making a OneToOne relation between User and UserProfile models that's why you are facing integrity error,
for fixing this you can change it to ForeignKey
Like :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
...
...
```

Comment: But you don't want a ForeignKey relationship between user and profile. It must be a One to One, otherwise you can have users with multiple profiles.