# Django Unique constraint failed for user field in model

Tags: python, django, forms

I've been trying to figure out how to save the user's id with in a model through a form, I keep getting `UNIQUE constraint failed: vapp_numobject.user_id`.

Here's my model:

```
class NumObject(models.Model):

    title= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number= models.IntegerField()
    ident= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NumObject,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

my forms.py:

```
class NumForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = NumObject
        fields = [
        'title',
        'number',               
        ]
```

and my view that saves the form:

```
@login_required
def post_createnum(request):
    form= NumForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)


    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    context= {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'num_form.html',context)
```

I'd like to be a able to sort a list of the NumObjects by user id, and I'm not sure if there's a better method in Django.  Any help is appreciated!

edit: I don't think it's quite the same as the other solution, since I'm trying to attach a user id to an object for querying later, instead of editing a users' id and saving it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Integrity error UNIQUE constraint failed: user\_profile.user\_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651688/django-integrity-error-unique-constraint-failed-user-profile-user-id)