# IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: user_userprofile.user_id

Tags: django

I define an extra `UserProfile` to extend `User`'s attributes as

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    SEX = (
        (1, 'male'),
        (0, 'woman'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sex = models.IntegerField(choices=SEX, default=1)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    about_me = models.TextField()
```

When I append UserProfile to existed User in Django shell

```
In[19]: for u in User.objects.all():
    ...:     profile = UserProfile(user=u)
    ...:     profile.save()
```

It report error:

```
IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: user_userprofile.user_id
```

I checked the answer [Django: Integrity error UNIQUE constraint failed: user_profile.user_id - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651688/django-integrity-error-unique-constraint-failed-user-profile-user-id), but have no ideas to solve my problem.

Comment: perfectly solved my problem, could you please transmit the short commit to answer. @KevinChristopherHenry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `OneToOneField` means that each `User` can only have one `UserProfile`. Since you're looping over every `User`, it will fail—that is, violate the unique database constraint that defines the `OneToOneField`—if there are any existing `UserProfiles`.

A simple way to check that is to look at `UserProfile.objects.count()`. If the answer to that is not `0`, then by definition you will get that `IntegrityError` when you run the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward, You defined a `OneToOne` relation between `User` and `UserProfile`, which means, only one `User` is associated with **one and only one** `UserProfile`.
I'm not sure about your logic, anyway try the following

```
for user in User.objects.all():
    if hasattr(user,'userprofile') and not user.userprofile:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Jerin Peter George's answer as it does not make a hit to the database, however, if you need access to the user profile instance while you iterate through this process, you can also use the built in get_or_create method bound to the Model's manager. . ie.

```
for u in User.objects.all():
    instance, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(
        user=u, 
        defaults={"""list of default keys and values"""})
    if created: 
        # update profile with form or other external data?
    else:
        # do other stuff 
    instance.save()
```

You could also check the count of the queryset

```
user_profiles = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=u)
instance = None
if user_profiles.count() == 0:
    # user profile doesn't exist create one
    instance = UserProfile.objects.create(user=u)
else:
    # user profile exists
    instance = user_profiles.first()
```