# UNIQUE constraint failed: home_profile.user_id - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am just trying to mix my Profile model with my User one. I was following this Django series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXunlJgeRcU&list=PLCC34OHNcOtoQCR6K4RgBWNi3-7yGgg7b

I accidentally deleted one of my users, so I tried recreating them again and got this error: UNIQUE constraint failed: home_profile.user_id

I tried solving the issue with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60282442/19641902 ... but it gave me another error: 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'
Also when I create the users in the database manually, it automatically creates three-four profiles in the User section of my database.

The following is the code after following the above StackOverflow answer

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# Create A User Profile Model
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
    follows = models.ManyToManyField("self", 
        related_name="followed_by",
        symmetrical=False,
        blank=True) 
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

# Create Profile When New User Signs Up
#@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        user_profile = Profile(user=instance)
        user_profile.save()
        # Have the user follow themselves
        user_profile.follows.set([instance.profile.id])
        user_profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

# Mix Profile info into User info
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile

# Extend User Model
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = User
    # Just display username fields on admin page
    fields = ["username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "password", "is_active", "is_staff", "is_superuser"]
    inlines = [ProfileInline]

# Unregister initial User
admin.site.unregister(User)

# Reregister User and Profile
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Likely using a `Porifle` model is not a good idea in the first place, using signals is another one: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html